how to display data from two Django model classes in a template by id?
I am new in django. I am try to make my first app called blog.This application contains two classes (with articles) finnews and fingram, I need to display all articles finnews and fingram on one template (I got it). I also need that from this template, the user clicks on the title of the article to go to the template with the full text of the article - and here with this I have problems. I'm reading the documentation and can't figure out how to fix the problem. Clicking on the finnews header results in a 404 error, and clicking on the fingram header results in a 'blogid() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'' error. So far I'm reading the documentation and can't figure out how to fix it.
urls.py for all project
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

views.py for blog app
def blogmain(request):
    all_fingrams = Fingram.objects.order_by('-id')
    all_finnewss = Finnews.objects.order_by('-id')
    
    data = {
        'all_fingrams': all_fingrams,
        'all_finnewss': all_finnewss,
    }
    return render(request,'blog/financial-news.html', data)
 
def blogid(request):
    single_fingram = get_object_or_404(Fingram, pk=id)
    single_finnews = get_object_or_404(Finnews, pk=id)
    
    data = {
        'single_fingram' : single_fingram,
        'single_finnews' : single_finnews,
    }
    return render(request,'blog/financialarticle.html', data)

urls.py for blog app
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.blogmain, name='blogmain'),
    path('<int:id>', views.blogid, name='blogid'),
]

model for blog app
class Fingram(models.Model):
    fingramarcticle_fullname = models.CharField()
    fingramarcticle_shortname = models.CharField()
    fingramarcticle_fulldesc = models.CharField()
    fingramarcticle_shortdesc = models.CharField()
    fingramarcticle_fulltext = models.CharField()
    fingramarcticle_smallimg = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    fingramarcticle_bigimg = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    fingramarcticle_seoimg = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    fingramarcticle_tags = models.CharField()
    fingramarcticle_titleseo = models.CharField()
    fingramarcticle_descseo = models.CharField()
    fingramarcticle_metakeywordsseo = models.CharField()
    fingramarcticle_createddate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    fingramarcticle_author = models.CharField()
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fingramarcticle_shortname
    
class Finnews(models.Model):
    finnewsarcticle_fullname = models.CharField()
    finnewsarcticle_shortname = models.CharField()
    finnewsarcticle_fulldesc = models.CharField()
    finnewsarcticle_shortdesc = models.CharField()
    finnewsarcticle_fulltext = models.CharField()
    finnewsarcticle_smallimg = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    finnewsarcticle_bigimg = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    finnewsarcticle_seoimg = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    finnewsarcticle_tags = models.CharField()
    finnewsarcticle_titleseo = models.CharField()
    finnewsarcticle_descseo = models.CharField()
    finnewsarcticle_metakeywordsseo = models.CharField()
    finnewsarcticle_createddate = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    finnewsarcticle_author = models.CharField()
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.finnewsarcticle_shortname

template
{% for finnews in all_finnewss %}
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card border-light mb-3">  
              <img src="{{ finnews.finnewsarcticle_smallimg.url }}" class="card-img-top rounded-bottom-1" alt="..." >
              <div class="card-body">
                <a class="card-title" href="{% url 'blogid' finnews.id %}">{{finnews.finnewsarcticle_shortname}}</h5></a>
                <p class="card-text">{{finnews.finnewsarcticle_shortdesc}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container lfs">
        <h1><a class="loadmore" href="{% url 'financialnews' %}">View all</h1></a>
      </div>
      <div class="container pt-3">
        <h1 class="fingram">Fingram</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="container pt-3 pb-4">
        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
          {% for fingram in all_fingrams %}
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card border-light mb-3">
              <img src="{{ fingram.fingramarcticle_smallimg.url }}" class="card-img-top rounded-bottom-1" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <a class="card-title" href="{% url 'blogid' fingram.id %}">{{fingram.fingramarcticle_shortname}}</h5></a>
                <p class="card-text">{{fingram.fingramarcticle_shortdesc}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}

Tried different views, but the error persists. Can you please tell me where I'm going wrong?

It is very weird that both items should always have the same id. Eventually it is likely the two will get out of sync.

One error has been addressed by @Serkan.  The other is likely due to the id's of two different models not synced (nor should you rely on them being the same!).  How to fix this depends on what you want, and to see that, I'd need to see your other template, the one that shows the full article (financialarticle.html).

Thanks for your help. There is a blog application. It should perform several tasks.First - using view blogmain to show the user 12 recent articles from financial literacy (fingram class in model) and financial news (finnews class in model). The second - when a user clicks on the title of an article, he or she will be taken to view blogid, where he or she will see the full text of the article. The third (it is not implemented yet) - the views allfinancialnews and allfingram will display all articles from financial news and financial literacy respectively.

I think that for the second task it would be better to create two views - financialgramarticle and financialnewsarticle, to display the full texts of the corresponding articles in them in detail using {{}}, I tried to do that, but there are errors there too. Maybe the problem can be solved by specifying fields with primary key in fingram/finnews classes and requesting it already?

I understand but I still need to see both templates.  Yes you'll probably need two views.

Ok. I made two views - financialnewsarticle and financialliteracyarticle and left the previous blogmain view.  def financialliteracyarticle(request, id):
single_fingram = get_object_or_404(Fingram, pk=id)
data = {
    'single_fingram' : single_fingram,
}
return render(request, 'blog/financial-literacy-blogarticle.html', data)

def financialnewsarticle(request, id):
single_finnews = get_object_or_404(Finnews, pk=id)
data = {
    'single_finnews' : single_finnews,
}
return render(request, 'blog/financial-news-blogarticle.html', data)


blog/urls.py urlpatterns = [
path('', views.blogmain, name='blogmain'),
path('int:id', views.financialliteracyarticle, name=
'financialliteracyarticle'
),
path('int:id', views.financialnewsarticle, name='financialnewsarticle'),
]

financial-literacy-blogarticle.html and financial-news-blogarticle.html {% load static %}
{{single_fingram.fingramarcticle_fullname}}
{{single_fingram.fingramarcticle_createddate}}
{% load static %}
{{single_finnews.finnewsarcticle_fullname}}
{{single_finnews.finnewsarcticle_createddate}}
The full text of the article on financial literacy opens correctly! But the full text of the article on financial news opens with error 404 -the current path,blog/16/, didn't match any of these. At the same time, the id of the article is displayed correctly in the address bar, i.e. equal to 16

The main template remained almost unchanged.I only changed the url from blogid to financialnewsarticle and financialliteracyarticle

def blogid(request,single_fingram_id,single_finnews_id): #You need to get the id here
    single_fingram = get_object_or_404(Fingram, pk=single_fingram_id)
    single_finnews = get_object_or_404(Finnews, pk=single_finnews_id)
    
    data = {
        'single_fingram' : single_fingram,
        'single_finnews' : single_finnews,
    }
    return render(request,'blog/financialarticle.html', data)

###########################
path('<int:single_fingram_id>/<int:single_finnews_id>', views.blogid, name='blogid')

###########################
 <a class="card-title" href="{% url 'blogid' fingram.id finnews.id %}">{{fingram.fingramarcticle_shortname}}</h5></a>


Inadvertently I forgot to include the id. Now added. But it doesn't change the problem.When you click on the finnews title you get a 404 error (the current path blog/16 didn't match any pf these).When you click on the fingram header you get a 404 error (no finnews matches the given query, the current path blog/3 matched the last one blog/ int:id [name='blogid']).

Are the ID's of the two queries the same?

I updated my old answer, can you try again?

thanks for help
id's not the same
i try your code, result: NoReverseMatch at /blog/
Reverse for 'blogid' with arguments '(3, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<single_fingram_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<single_finnews_id>[0-9]+)\Z']
Error during template rendering
Reverse for 'blogid' with arguments '(3, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<single_fingram_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<single_finnews_id>[0-9]+)\Z']
No get data, no post data, no files data

Can you close this question and ask another question?
